# MVP pattern WinForms: How to correctly update UI?

Tags: c#, winforms, mvp

Given the following MVP setup how would you update the winforms UI? This is my first time trying to implement MVP and I believe I have been following a "Passive View" implementation of MVP.

I really didn't want my model to reference the presenter because I thought that was against the idea of the MVP pattern but then isn't the purpose of the Presenter to update the View? And obviously didn't want my Model updating my view. Let me know if I have made a mistake in my thinking though!

```
    public class HomePresenter
    {
        Item item;
        Model model

        SomeTask()
        {
            model.AnotherTask(item);
        }
    }

    public class Model
    {
        public void AnotherTask(Item item)
        {
            /* SOME COMPLEX LOGIC HERE */

            if (item.BoolProperty)
                // How do I write "Success" to richtextbox in View
            else
                // How do I write "Failure to richtextbox in View
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Presenter should sync your View and your Model. The View only shows the data. The Model know's the business logic and "real" data and the Presenter link the Model data to your View. So you won't access the Richtextbox from your Model. Instead you do this from your Presenter. To stay independent you should use Interfaces. So you have no direct access to View elements in Presenter or Model.

> Create an IView Interface and an IModel Interface. Both of them are
>   known by your Presenter.

Your example could look like this:

```
public class HomeView : IHomeView
{
   public string Text 
   {
      get {return richtextbox.Text;}
      set {richtextbox.Text = value;}
   }
}

public class HomePresenter
    {
        IHomeView view;
        IModel model;

        HomePresenter(IHomeView view, IModel model)
        {
           view = view;
           model = model;

           //Update View
           view.Text = model.Text;
        }

        public void UpdateModel
        {
           model.Text = view.Text; //Set the Model Property to value from Richtextbox
        }         
    }

    public class Model : IModel
    {
        public string Text {get;set} //Property which represent Data from Source like DB or XML etc.
    }
```

You find another example [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14660/WinForms-Model-View-Presenter).

Comment: I think I understand, I do have a question though, say in my Model I have:
`
        MethodA() {
            Text += "one string" + Environment.NewLine;
            await Task.Delay(5000);
            `Text += "two string" + Environment.NewLine; }`
then obviously after the model is done executing the method I can call UpdateModel() in the HomePresenter, but it "chunks" the textbox updates rather than as they happen. Is there any work around to this?

Comment: I don't really understand the Problem. You mean a UpdateView Method instead UpdateModel i guess. But if MethodA build your string, the view needs to wait until the string is ready. Or do you want to show half true information? Further if you want to show first part of MethodA in your View just split your MethodA in separate Methods and call them in order in your Update Routines.

Comment: Sorry I did misunderstand! Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: @John Cover Your welcome. Don't forget to accept answer please ;)